# Installing Python SDK for NAO robots

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, nao-robot

I'm trying to follow the documentation provided by Aldebaran [here](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/dev/python/install_guide.html#python-install-guide) in order to get my NAO ready for Python programming. I correctly downloaded the NAOqi framework adapted to my OS (linux 64 bits) then I typed the command line `$ export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/python-sdk` which, if I understand things right, should be typed in a terminal and not in a Python shell.

Then I typed `import naoqi` in a Python shell and got the `ImportError: No module named naoqi` error, so I tried [troubleshooting](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/dev/python/tips-and-tricks.html#python-sdk-troubleshooting) and typed

```
import sys
print "\n".join(sys.path)
```

in the same Python shell and got the following output:

```
/home/*****
    /usr/bin
    /usr/lib/python2.7
    /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol`
```

So I indeed don't have `/path/to/python-sdk` as I should, but not I'm blocked. What should I do to solve that?

(I am new to Linux, Python, and NAO, so perhaps the answer is obvious, but I've been trying to configure NAO for almost a week, so I definitely need some help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have naoqi installed in `/home/user/naoqi`

1.- Open a text editor (Kate, Gedit,... whatever)

2.- Open the file `/home/user/.profile`

3.- At the end of the file, add the following line

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/user/naoqi
```

4.- Reboot (Close your session and login again also works, but just to be sure)

**NOTE**: Remember to change **/home/user/naoqi** with the correct path

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a while until I came across the [Python SDK - Troubleshooting](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/python/tips-and-tricks.html) page which states that the path to the naoqi.py file that should be on your PYTHONPATH is `/path/to/python-sdk/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

I added the following line to my .bashrc file

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/naoqi/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and then ran `source .bashrc` in the terminal.

You can test if the path has been added correctly by running the following lines of code in a python2 terminal.

```
import sys
print "\n".join(sys.path)
```

You should see your above path in the list.
Lastly try `import naoqi` in a python2 terminal to confirm.