# Don't know how to set PYTHONPATH variable for Naoqi python-sdk

Tags: python, sdk, nao-robot

[The selected text in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3fyl.png)

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/python/install_guide.html

I am following the link above to install the python-sdk on my mac (v.10.13) for Naoqi.

`export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/python-sdk/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

what does `/path/to/python-sdk` mean ?

I am not able to find any path of this sort, `lib/python2.7/site-packages`

How and where am I supposed to set this environment variable ?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403634/installing-python-sdk-for-nao-robots/59164994#59164994) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that instead of following that procedure for manually adding the SDK to your python path, you may simply want to do `pip install qi` (if you have pip working on your computer), and it will do all that for you.

Otherwise, to install it "manually" as explained on that page:

You need to download the version of the Python SDK you want [from this page](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/resources/software/language/en-gb), unzip somewhere on your computer, and get the path of *that* folder, more specifically the `\lib` subfolder in it. This is the path you want to add to your pythonpath. How you do that exactly will depend of your OS, see [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html) for a breakdown for Windows, Mac and Linux.